# Android Studio debugger doesn't work when using inline/crossinline functions

Tags: android, multithreading, android-studio, kotlin

I am currently trying to implement a web service on Kotlin, the solution that i came out with works as expected, but the Android Studio debugger doesn't.

This is my code simplified:

```
fun loop(){
    Handler().postDelayed({
        subscribeCommand<TestModel> {
            println("RESULT")
            loop()
        }
    }, 1000)
}

fun startRequest(callback : () -> Unit){
    callback()
}

inline fun <reified T> subscribeCommand(crossinline onResult : (MutableList<T>) -> Unit){
    startRequest {
        onResult(mutableListOf<T>())
    }
}
```

This code prints "Result" in the console every second when calling `loop()`

I have an extra function `startRequest()`, thats because i will be using that callback on something else.

When placing a breakpoint in the `println("RESULT")` it works the first time the application starts, but then i remove the breakpoint and continue the execution.
After a few seconds i place the breakpoint back, the code still runs as expected, but the debugger doesn't catch it anymore.

I need to use generic types and that's why i am using these inline/crossinline function and i haven't found a different approach to this.

This is what i am using
Android Studio 3.4.1
Gradle 3.4.1
Kotlin 1.3.41
MinSdkVersion 16
TargetSdkVersion 28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue by changing the parameter from `crossinline` to `noinline`